# How to make X cell blank until Y cell filled up?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to hide **@1234** I mean not apply the formula, until I write something on **C** column and also make the formula an array and no need to drag it down:

[image: example]

Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XHoxD-hNmpUOMVm_u-cz-4ESrabodsrS0fIfaN-n4js/edit

Thank you!

Comment: You can do that using the arrayformula you already have in column `I`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C14), "", TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C14:C," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))& "@1234")
```

You should use the `IF` function to check whether the respective cell `ISBLANK` or not.

The syntax of `IF`:

```
=IF(CONDITION_TO_CHECK, WHAT_TO_SHOW_IF_CONDITION_IS_TRUE, WHAT_TO_SHOW_OTHERWISE)
```